# Embedding a range in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of 14 columns and I want to pull select ones into a new dataframe. 
Let's say I want column 0 then column 8-14

```
  dfnow = pd.Series([df.iloc[row_count,0], \
                    df.iloc[row_count,8], \
                    df.iloc[row_count,9], \
                    ....
```

Works but seems clumsy

I'd like to write

```
  dfnow = pd.Series([df.iloc[row_count,0], \
          df.iloc[row_count, range (8, 14)]])
```

But this throws a ValueError: Wrong number of items passed

Now, from the answer below, I know I can create two separate sereis and concatenate them, but that seems a little sub-optimal as well.

[Adding pandas Series with different indices without getting NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504493/adding-pandas-series-with-different-indices-without-getting-nans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can convert all values to `lists` and then create `Series`, but then lost indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

row_count = 1

print (df.iloc[row_count, range (2, 4)])
C    8
D    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64

dfnow = pd.Series([df.iloc[row_count,0]]  + df.iloc[row_count, range (2, 4)].tolist())
print (dfnow)
0    2
1    8
2    3
dtype: int64
```

---

Or you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), then indices are column names:

```
row_count = 1

a = df.iloc[row_count, range (2, 4)]
b = df.iloc[row_count, range (4, 6)]

print (a)
C    8
D    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64

print (b)
E    3
F    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64

print (pd.concat([a,b]))
C    8
D    3
E    3
F    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

But if need add scalar (`a`), it is a bit complicated - need `Series`:

```
row_count = 1

a = pd.Series(df.iloc[row_count, 0], index=[df.columns[0]])
b = df.iloc[row_count, range (2, 4)]
c = df.iloc[row_count, range (4, 6)]

print (a)
A    2
dtype: int64

print (b)
C    8
D    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64

print (c)
E    3
F    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64

print (pd.concat([a,b,c]))
A    2
C    8
D    3
E    3
F    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked, and I maintained the indices via: ....df.iloc[row_count, range(9,14)].tolist(),index= columns). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(5,6), columns=list('abcdef'))

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   0   1   2   3   4   5
1   6   7   8   9  10  11
2  12  13  14  15  16  17
3  18  19  20  21  22  23
4  24  25  26  27  28  29

In [54]: df[[0,2,4]]
Out[54]:
    a   c   e
0   0   2   4
1   6   8  10
2  12  14  16
3  18  20  22
4  24  26  28
```

concatenating (reshaping) columns `0`,`2`,`4` into single series:

```
In [68]: df[[0,2,4]].values.T.reshape(-1,)
Out[68]: array([ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24,  2,  8, 14, 20, 26,  4, 10, 16, 22, 28])

In [69]: pd.Series(df[[0,2,4]].values.T.reshape(-1,))
Out[69]:
0      0
1      6
2     12
3     18
4     24
5      2
6      8
7     14
8     20
9     26
10     4
11    10
12    16
13    22
14    28
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. i think the reshape would work, and is probably the more accepted procedure for what I was trying to accomplish +1

Answer (score 1):

consider the `df`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(150).reshape(-1, 15),
                  columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:15]))
df
```

[image]

use `np.r_` to construct the array neccesary for the slice you want

```
np.r_[0, 8:14]

array([ 0,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

then slice

```
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, 8:14]]
```

[image]